# UWP: Access to UI elements of others apps

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I need to know the UI elements, or the XAML tree of apps the user has started. Is there a way to do this with UWP APIs ? Because I have an android app which is able to ask user permission to retrieve this data. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All application are runned inside a sandbox and you can't get out if it to get information about other apps. Maybe if you describe what you need it for I can help you a other direction

Comment: I wan't to create an auto filling experience for other apps the user install, but I think without this type of api present in windows sdk it will be difficult